# IdentityServer4 + Auth0

Tags: c#, identityserver4, auth0

I would like to make an identity service with IdServer4 that outsources the 'authentication' part to Auth0 - Auth0 deals with Single Sign On and other stuff and does a great job - so no need to reinvent the wheel. But I would like to embed this in an identity server (pref. IdentityServer4), that handles authentication via Auth0 and handles authorization itself (claims and scopes) for users & machines.

Machines would acquire their token through the tokenClient via so-called Client Credentials (https://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html).

```
public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients =>
    new List<Client>
    {
        new Client
        {
            ClientId = "client",

            // no interactive user, use the clientid/secret for authentication
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,

            // secret for authentication
            ClientSecrets =
            {
                new Secret("secret".Sha256())
            },

            // scopes that client has access to
            AllowedScopes = { "api1" }
        }
    };
```

The machine 2 machine auth works. But how can the identity server make sure that 'users' log in via Auth0 (SSO) and then get an access token from IdentityServer4 itself (just like the machines), instead of getting the token from Auth0 itself. I have implemented Auth0 as a external ID Provider:

```
   services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie()
        .AddOpenIdConnect("Auth0", options => {
            options.Authority = "auth0domain";
            options.ClientId = "clientId";
            options.ClientSecret = "secret";
            ...
        });
```

For the rest, see : https://auth0.com/blog/using-csharp-extension-methods-for-auth0-authentication/

When triggering the Authentication via await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync(); the user can login. And afterwards he or she can logout. This works fine. But the user acquires an access token from Auth0 itself and I would like to replace it by a token generated by IdSrv4. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Identity Server as the base authentication server and configure SSO as an external login. Just like when you login a website using google, facebook, etc. The only consideration is that the SSO server should support a standard like OIDC. Take a look at
https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/ui/login/external/
https://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/signin_external_providers.html
You can do any authentication stuff (e.g. adding claims) at login callback handler

Answer (score 0):

Are you tied to IdentityServer4? Might be worth looking into [OpenIddict](https://dev.to/robinvanderknaap/setting-up-an-authorization-server-with-openiddict-part-i-introduction-4jid) as an alternative. I've just implemented this and an API secured by it using the provided tokens - worked a treat.

Apologies if I've missed the point of your question